# Android M app update and Permission for a Sync Adapter

Tags: android, calendar, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-syncadapter

I have an app using a AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter for syncing a calendar.
We are working on a build for android M. I have the calendar permission requests working in all cases except where the user already has the syncing setup and then upgrades our app from a non android M build to the new M build.

A] I can check the permission the first time the user opens the app after he upgraded it, but he may not open the app for a few weeks, during which his calendar will not sync.

B] I am heading toward the following option: The background sync service would start an activity that displays an explanation why we now need calendar permission because of the upgrade to M.

My question is:
Is B] the best option ?

Comment: Just a note that apps upgrading from targeting <23 to target API 23 will start with any previously accepted permissions as granted by default. That doesn't fix the issue where the user manually disables the permission from within the Settings screen so you'll want to handle this case anyways.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source for that? The reason i'm asking is before 23, there is no concept of "accepted permission" as far as i know so I am not even sure how that is technically possible. Do you mean whatever was in the manifest if the previous version would automatically be granted ?

Comment: Correct. The button in the Play Store for the permissions dialog when using install time permissions (i.e., targeting <API 23 and/or running on a <API 23 device) is 'Accept' - any permissions granted through install time permissions are granted when moving to an API 23+target API 23 setup.

Comment: Just tested an update, you are correct! If you have this as a separate answer i'll mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: You'll still want to manage the case where the user has set up syncing, but then disabled the calendar permission manually via the Settings app. In those cases, the already accepted answer by CommonsWare is the correct solution and also covers your initial concern. Just an extra dose of knowledge to go with your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is B] the best option ?

IMHO, no. Raise a `Notification`, alerting the user of the need to grant the permission. When the user taps on the `Notification`, *then* go through `requestPermissions()` and ask the user for the permissions that you need. If the user ignores the `Notification`, remind them periodically (e.g., once a day) with a fresh `Notification`.

This achieves your objective of alerting the user to the problem without interfering with whatever they happen to be doing at the time you decide that you need this permission.